# Read UTF16 as bytes

Tags: c#, .net, character-encoding

**tl;dr** How do I read variable-length-encoded text using `stream.ReadByte()`?

**Long version:**

I'm trying to read a file that has some text and some binary data. This created a problem using approaches like `StreamReader`s, and therefore I'm reading the bytes and converting them to text. As long as the text is ASCII, this is simple, because one byte converts into one character.

But when the text is known to be encoded in UTF16 - the length of a character is variable. So how can I use `stream.ReadByte()` and transform it into UTF16?

Comment: Text encoded in utf16 is no more and no less variable in length than text encoded in ascii.  You are focusing on the wrong problem, decoding a single byte or a single character or a single codepoint at a time is just not very sensible.  Encoding.GetString() requires byte[] no matter how you swing that cat.

Comment: @HansPassant With ASCII I just read bytes until one is equal to the ACII value of  `'\n'`. Then I feed all of those bytes to `GetString`. With UTF I have no (simple) way for checking for end of line.

Comment: That is not at all different for utf-16, use ReadUInt16().  A codepoint that takes 2 elements will never match '\n'.

Comment: @HansPassant `Text encoded in utf16 is no more and no less variable in length than text encoded in ascii.` - What do you mean? ASCII is one byte per one character. UTF16 can be different number of bytes for different characters.

Comment: @HansPassant And how will I know whether to read one Int16 or two of them? `A codepoint that takes 2 elements will never match '\n'` - That is exactly my question - How can I test for a newline without knowing whether I'm reading the _only_ Int16, or just the first (or second) of 2 of them who make up one character?

Comment: You are testing for equality, not inequality.  As long as it doesn't match '\n', and it won't if they are surrogates, then you don't care what it is and keep reading.

Comment: @HansPassant Did I understand you correctly that there is no UTF16 character that has 000A as ***either its first two bytes or its second two bytes*** besides [newline](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/000A/index.htm)?

Comment: Yes, that's a design feature of UTF-16. (Similarly for UTF-8.) In UTF-16, the code units that are pairs are in distinct first (high) ranges and second (low) ranges. From the perspective of the older UCS-2 encoding that UTF-16 is based on, they are surrogates since they are not actual codepoints. So, you can grab any properly aligned two bytes of UTF-16 encoded text and know if that code unit is a whole codepoint, or the first of a pair or the second of a pair. '\n' (U+000A) has the one '\u000A' code unit and not being in either range of pairs '\u000A' can only be U+000A.

Comment: @TomBlodget Thanks. I'm now trying to understand your comment. I just asked a [question about UTF16 and how it works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44243549/how-does-utf16-encode-characters).

Comment: However, 0x000A (or 0x0A00, depending on your endianness is), could be in your binary data and not text, right?

Comment: @TomBlodget The text comes before the data and there's a text cue for the data so I know when the text ends and the data begins.

Comment: @TomBlodget `not being in either range of pairs` - what ranges?

Comment: [C# Char](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.char(v=vs.110).aspx) has methods. [Java Character](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html) is more detailed and has constants. [JavaScript String.prototype.charAt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charAt) has short descriptions but lots of examples with comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to help by the comments and in an answer to [another question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44243549/how-does-utf16-encode-characters) I now know that since all of the text will be lines, all I need to do is read 2 bytes and check whether they are '\n'. UTF16 is such that it won't be '\n' as only one part of a surrogate pair.