# How does UTF16 encode characters?

Tags: text, unicode, encoding, character-encoding, language-agnostic

**EDIT**

Since it seems I'm not going to get an answer to the general question. I'll restrict it to one detail: Is my understanding of the following, correct?

That surrogates work as follows:

1. If the first pair of bytes is *not* between D800 and DBFF - there
   will not be a second pair.
2. If it is between D800 and DBFF - a) there will be a second pair b)
   the second pair will be in the range of DC00 and DFFF.
3. There is no single pair UTF16 character with a value between D800
   and DBFF.
4. There is no single pair UTF16 character with a value between DC00
   and DFFF.

Is this right?

**Original question**

I've tried reading about UTF16 but I can't seem to understand it. What are "planes" and "surrogates" etc.? Is a "plane" the first 5 bits of the first byte? If so, then why not 32 planes since we're using those 5 bits anyway? And what are surrogates? Which bits do they correspond to?

I do understand that UTF16 is a way to encode Unicode characters, and that it sometimes encodes characters using 16 bits, and sometimes 32 bits, no more no less. I *assume* that there is some list of values for the first 2 bytes (which are the most significant ones?) which indicates that a second 2 bytes will be present.

But instead of me going on about what I *don't* understand, perhaps someone can make some order in this?

Comment: @downvoters Care to help out as well?

Comment: I suspect they are because "[does not show any research effort](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/223482)". Do you have questions about the [UTF-16 FAQ](http://unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html#UTF16)?

Comment: @TomBlodget Thanks. I'm not sure how I'm supposed to _show_ the effort. Include links to the articles I've read (and did not understand)? How would that help the question? But anyway, you might be right that that is why it's being downvoted. I'm now reading the link you provided me with. Thanks.

Comment: @TomBlodget I have a bit of a hard time understanding the actual code there (I'm familiar with C#, not C) but basically I understand that if the first pair of bytes is between D800 and DBFF - then a second pair will be needed. But what does the trailing surrogates mean? They _seem_ to mean that if the _second_ pair of bytes is between DC00 and DFFF, then a second pair of bytes will be needed. Which doesn't make any sense, of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes on all four.

To clarify, the term "pair" in UTF-16 refers to two UTF-16 code units, the first in the range D800-DBFF, the second in DC00-DFFF.

A code unit is 16-bits (2 bytes), typically written as an unsigned integer in hexadecimal  (0x000A). The order of the bytes (0x00 0x0A or 0x0A 0x00) is specified by the author or indicated with a BOM (0xFEFF) at the beginning of the file or stream. (The BOM is encoded with the same algorithm as the text but is not part of the text. Once the byte order is determined and the bytes are reordered to the native ordering of the system, it typically is discarded.)

Comment: I'd just like to verify that you understood that when I wrote "pair" in the 4 questions, I meant a pair of bytes. And "single pair" meant a character denoted by 2 bytes (as opposed to 4).

Comment: And thanks for all of your help. I wouldn't even be able to ask the revised question without your help. Particularly [this UTF16 FAQ link](http://unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html#UTF16).